# In the delayed-choice quantum eraser experiment what is the pattern at D0 if the beam splitters at the which path detectors D3 and D4 are removed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment, quantum-eraser

Let me first, as a reference for my question, show the graphical description of the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment and explain my understanding of it.

This is the experimental setup:
[image]

My understanding of the experiment outcomes is the following:

1. The overall figure at screen D0 is a no-interference pattern
2. A photon hitting D3 can have passed just through the first slit, say slit A
3. A photon hitting D4 can have passed just through the second slit, say slit B
4. A photon hitting either D1 or D2 can have passed either from slit A or slit B
5. The coincidence counter allows splitting the figure at D0 into the separate figures determined by the photons whose entangled twins hit either D1, D2, D3 or D4, and it turned out that:
   a) The sub-figures determined by the twins of photons hitting D3 and D4 are  no-interference patterns
   b) The sub-figures determined by the twins of photons hitting D1 and D2 are  interference patterns

Allowing that my understanding is basically correct (pls comment my mistakes if any),  my question is the following: **has the experiment been done also without beam splitters BSa and BSb (thus also without detectors D3 and D4)? if so, what pattern has appeared at screen D0? an interference pattern or not?**

Comment: Note there is no "interference pattern" at detectors D1 and D2, because D1 and D2 just count the number of photons that hit them.  The interference happens by analyzing the results of many such photon detections, and that's all done in the Coincidence Counter part of the experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, fixing the description. The question is although still valid.

Comment: I agree! I just think that clarification is important, because in order to understand this experiment, we have to understand *where the interference occurs*, or at least, how we measure it, and it's not by shining light on a screen and seeing an interference pattern (at least, not at D1 and D2; I'm not so sure about D0).